# reading microdata from an ajax loaded page

Tags: php, ajax, google-plus, share, microdata

a product page i am working on, has the following structure:

the page itself: `detail.php`
header of page: `top.php`
footer of page: `footer.php`

detail.php include both top and footer (which contains html header, javascript and so on)
detail itself it is almost empty, once loaded it call an ajax posting some params, and fill a div with the result (the product detail itself);

im facing the following problem, i declare the page as

```
itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"
```

(i tried both in top.php as part of html tag and inside loaddetail.php as a part of a div;
the all the field loaded from loaddetail got their right itemprop

google (and other test tool) seems to totally ignore it, it looks like they don't like the `itemprop` attribute not loaded at the beginning, but loaded with an ajax post.

(i manually tried to put various itemprop both in top and in detail, and it works correctly, just when the itemprop belongs to tags that are "attached" to page with an ajax call)

Comment: This might help: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: that looks really useful, but i am not looking to index the page (even if i will surely implent this), i am just trying to have the g+ share button include an image, a title and so, in its share windows, at the moment (since the content is not present in the page but loaded with ajax, the content is non-existent for the share button); i was trying to have the button load the ajax url instead of the main url (and it worked, i had the itemprop filled right), but the i can't override the url, so it happen to share the wrong url